# PHP age range selection from a field saved as a date

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have been having some trouble with querying an age range from a drop-down of choices (1-99) and am just starting to confuse myself looking over it again and again.

Some context: online listing of students for a school, and I am using bootstrap.

If I can figure out the "from an age" then the "to age" shouldnt be too hard, so I'll focus on just the first part in this.

Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="from_age">From Age</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="from_age" id="from_age">
       <option value="">-- Choose an Age --</option>
       <? for ($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++) { ?>
          <option value="<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i; ?></option>
       <?}?>
   </select>
</div>
```

Later on in code... this is the part of the query that I am having trouble with. All the other queries in this chain work fine. This adds in the WHERE part of the query btw.

```
if ($_REQUEST['from_age']) {
   $query .= " And DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(student.dob)), '%Y') >= '".($_REQUEST['from_age'])."'";
   $link_params .= "&from_age=".$_REQUEST['from_age'];
}
```

The student table in the database stores the "dob" (date of birth) as a Date (1985-05-20).

I tried something like this, but I know the logic is wrong and it will try to search for only the year. Drawing a blank on how to fix this though.

```
And FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - TO_DAYS(student.dob)) + DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y') >= ".($_REQUEST['from_age'] + date("Y"))." ";
```

Comment: Are you trying to get all records where the student age is greater than the from_age in the dropdown? If that is the case perhaps 'WHERE student.dob >= 'DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '".($_REQUEST['from_age'])."' YEAR), '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Just a hint, after `<option value="">-- CHoose an Age --</option>`, consider `<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++) { echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>"; } ?>` (properly indented) instead of what you did.

Comment: And then you can pass the date calculations to PHP and give the result as parameter to your SQL query instead of making your DB do the math job.

Comment: I prefer to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` and `NOW()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: Shad, your option works great when testing my query in phpMyAdmin. However when running in my code it just seems to ignore the statement completely and load all the results. I don't know what is causing it, but if I had to guess I would say the $_REQUEST is not getting the value selected from the dropdown for some reason.

Comment: Nvm, it is working now. Also, it seems a little counter intuitive but if you have a range with that code, the from_age should be <= and the to_age should be >=. 
Thank you very much for the help Shad. You should make your first suggestion an answer instead of a comment so I can accept it as an answer.
I didn't know that function existed, thank you A.O.
I prefer to break php and use html when possible but I understand why you wouldn't want people using shortcode for the echo Aedix Rhinedale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL `DATEDIFF` function to calculate difference between  the user's dob and MySQL `CURDATE()` function. see example below.

```
+------+---------------------+
| name | dob                 |
+------+---------------------+
| Joe  | 2000-08-02 05:15:17 |
| John | 1978-08-02 00:15:00 |
| Jake | 2015-07-07 00:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
```

Query

```
select users.name ,floor(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),users.dob )/365) as active_days
from users;
```

output

```
+------+-------------+
| name | active_days |
+------+-------------+
| Joe  |          15 |
| John |          37 |
| Jake |           0 |
+------+-------------+
```

or you can supply the user's selected date to your query and calculate dob. 
Hope this help.